# How to change previously assigned variable with a function in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a game in which I have a login screen followed by a main menu followed by the main game window. Within the main menu, I have a button which should change the difficulty of the game which will lead to a change in radius of a target. The higher the difficulty, the smaller the radius. When I assign my variable radius and then try and change it with the button (inside the class) it will not work and will instead use the previously defined radius.

I've tried setting lots of different global variables.

```
difficulty = -1

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.difficulty = -1

        self.grid()
        self.login = self.create_main()
        self.read = None



    def changeVariable1(self):
        self.difficulty = 12

    def changeVariable2(self):
        self.difficulty = 16

    def changeVariable3(self):
        self.difficulty = 20


    def diff(self):
        global radius
        if difficulty == 12:
            radius = (30)
        elif difficulty == 16:
            radius = (20)
        elif difficulty == 20:
            radius = (10)

    def create_read(self):
        read = Toplevel()

        Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1()).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2()).grid(row=3, column=3)
        Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3()).grid(row=3, column=4)

        return read

root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect when I click a button easy, medium, hard it changes the difficulty which will set the radius to the respective value.

Comment: You never change the global variable `difficulty` from `-1`, so I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answers provided. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

I bet the error is how you call `Button.__init__()`.

```
    Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1()).grid(row=3, column=2)
    Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2()).grid(row=3, column=3)
    Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3()).grid(row=3, column=4)
```

You are trying to assign a `command` to the `Button` like this `command=self.changeVariable1()`

With Python, functions and methods are all instances, `command` expects a instance of function, but you give it the result of `self.changeVariable1()`'.

Removing parenthesis should fix it:

```
Button([...], command=self.changeVariable1)
```

---

Edit: I bet [bumblebee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6506040/bumblebee)'s answer is also true and you need both fixes :)

Answer (score 0):

In your class APplication, you are declaring the `difficulty` variable and initialising it with certain values. 
This is the class variable which can be accessed using `self.difficulty`.
But when you change the radius value based on the `difficulty` variable, you are actually accessing the global instance.
There is no need for you to keep a global instance of the variable `difficulty`.

The modification is:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.difficulty = -1

        self.grid()
        self.login = self.create_main()
        self.read = None

    def changeVariable1(self):
        self.difficulty = 12

    def changeVariable2(self):
        self.difficulty = 16

    def changeVariable3(self):
        self.difficulty = 20


    def diff(self):
        global radius
        if self.difficulty == 12:
            radius = (30)
        elif self.difficulty == 16:
            radius = (20)
        elif self.difficulty == 20:
            radius = (10)

    def create_read(self):
        read = Toplevel()

        Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1()).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2()).grid(row=3, column=3)
        Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3()).grid(row=3, column=4)

        return read

root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps!.

Comment: Thank you and Arount! I am having another error where I try and use difficulty in a different function outside of the class:   def play():                                                                                    xxx                                                                                                  else: screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // difficulty)                                  play()

Comment: screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // difficulty)
NameError: name 'difficulty' is not defined

Comment: That's because you have defined `difficulty` as a class variable. If you need `difficulty` out of the class, define a method which will return the current value of `difficulty`.